# Which Kernel file is responsible for setting up 32 bit or 64 bit mode

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm going through Linux Kernel code and interested in knowing which file will be responsible for setting long mode to support 64 bit or which will be telling the OS going to boot would be 32 bit or 64 bit??

Is it bootloader code responsible to set this mode up??

Answer (score 0):

The boot loader (usually GRUB) is booting some Linux kernel.  This kernel may be a 32 bits kernel (then able only to run 32 bits programs) or a 64 bits kernel.

64 bits Linux kernels are able to run thru [execve(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html) syscalls either 32 bits binary executable program (in a 32 bits process) or 64 bits program

So most kernels are 64 bits and can run both 32 or 64 bits [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executables.

I guess that, depending how they are booted, Linux kernels start in 32 bits mode (at least when booted by GRUB).

Comment: Thanks Basile ,so I can find that particular code in bootloader part.

Comment: No, the 32 -> 64 bits transition happens in the kernel. The 16 -> 32 bits transition might happen in GRUB